# How do you change the scroll position on mobile browsers using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, skrollr

I'm using skrollr on a mobile web site, and it works fine when you use your finger to scroll the page up/down.  However, I have some buttons to click that jump to specific sections of the page; on desktop browsers it works fine, but on mobile browsers the page doesn't scroll.  I've found that on mobile browsers, when you scroll the page with your finger the window.pageYOffset, window.scrollY, documentElement.scrollTop, and body.scrollTop values don't change.

I'm using window.scrollTo(x,y) to do the page scrolling, and on  mobile that does change the scrollY value but skrollr doesn't do anything.  I've also tried using jQuery's scrollTop() and offset() methods, both work on desktop but not on mobile.

You can see a test page here: http://www.friendlyvengeance.com/dev/skrollr_test/

Is there any way to programmatically change the scroll position on mobile browsers?  And what property is skrollr reading when the user scrolls with their finger?

Comment: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#mobile-support

Comment: I've read that, but I'm using fixed elements.  If I add the skrollr-body id then it no longer works correctly.  I can try to get the effect I want without using fixed elements, but then how do I allow a user to tap a button and jump to a specific scroll position on mobile?

Comment: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#setscrolltoptop-force--false

Comment: Ok I feel like a moron now because I actually read that a few weeks ago but I was using jQuery out of habit.  Thanks for the replies, everything is working great now.